# How to prevent key repeat for my mute/unmute key?

Tags: sound, keyboard

I have set a very low key repeat delay because I like it … makes me feel working faster :-)

However, this creates problems with the hardware mute/unmute button on my computer (a Lenovo ThinkPad X201): when pressing it, often the key repeat will kick in and will both mute and unmute it again.

Can I disable key repeat for a single key? If so, how for this button?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable key repeat for individual keys with the `xset` utility. It works on X.org level, independent of yourdesktop environment. For the mute/unmute key, you would do this:

1. Start the X event tester program `xev` in a terminal, make its window the active one and press the mute/unmute button to find out the keycode of your button. Look for a `KeyPress` or `KeyRelease` message containing `XF86AudioMute` in your terminal, like this one:

   ```
   KeyRelease event, serial 48, synthetic NO, window 0x4a00001,
       root 0x98, subw 0x0, time 277961250, (-222,299), root:(879,323),
       state 0x0, keycode 121 (keysym 0x1008ff12, XF86AudioMute), same_screen YES,
       XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
       XFilterEvent returns: False
   ```

   This is from a ThinkPad X201 and shows that the keycode is 121.
2. Execute the following command to disable key repeat for the key with keycode 121 (or whatever you found if your hardware is different):

   ```
   xset -r 121
   ```
3. If this successfully disabled key repeat for the mute/unmute key, put this `xset -r 121` command into your autostart to activate it on system start. Since it's X.org specific, it is ok to put it into your desktop environment's autostart configuration. No need to have it before X.org starts, and also not on the X.org login screen.